# Can I use PC3L memory module in a PC3 slot

Tags: memory, ddr3

I apologize if this is not the right *exchange to ask, but this is the closest one I guess. My ThinkPad X201 supports only PC3 memory and I have one extra module PC3L (stands for Low Voltage AFAIK).

Can I try to put it in or is this dangerous? **Can I use PC3 and PC3L modules together?**

I do not want to damage my laptop, thus asking :-)

Thanks

Comment: By the way, this question has been deleted from SuperUser and I was instructed to go to Electronics site... Now it's back.

Comment: To answer the "can I use PC3 and PC3L together" check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/662033/can-you-have-pc3l-and-pc3-ram-together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your laptop supports DDR3 (PC3- refers to DDR3) SODIMM memory, if the PC3L memory which you have is SODIMM (204pin) then you can install it with out any issues else if it is DIMM (240-pin) then don't even think about it. You will not be harming your system in anyway by installing the low voltage memory, if the memory is incompatible then it may not boot. Usually, the laptop will work fine with 1.35v memory (Low voltage) since your laptop comes with either i3, i5 or i7 processor. Moreover, Crucial.com has listed 1.35v SODIMM memory.

BTW, it is weird to hear that you were able to install a DDR3 memory in DDR2 slot. DDR3 and DDR2 memory have different notch positions on the module and so they will not fit. Moreover, they are electrically incompatible.

Hope that helps!!! :-)

Comment: Ok I will try that today. I want to use 4GB PC3 with 4GB PC3L together, I hope that works. Yeah, you are right, DDR2/DDR3 is wrong, I meant I was using DDR2 module with faster speed in slower speed socket. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the slot marked pc3l only, then pc3 may NOT work at all. Even if same 1.35v SODIMM.  I have Dell inspiron 15 5000 series,  SODIMM 204pin slot, DDR3 PC3 DDR3 1.35v, 1600HZ memory not working. I tried crucial and Samsung brand PC3 DDR3 1.35v, 1600HZ memory,  both not working.  Only PC3L memory work.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence of what did and didn't work in your computer isn't really a definitive answer to the question of what the requirements are for the Thinkpad, or whether there is any danger.

Comment: The answer is still relevant because if the slot is low power only it won't power a normal chip.  It will only power a low power one.  The anecdote just provides an example.

Comment: This is for a reverse example. OP has a low-powered chip and a high-powered slot. Your answer is for a high-powered chip in a low-powered slot.