# Can you have PC3L and PC3 RAM together?

Tags: laptop, memory, compatibility, sodimm

I have a pair of DDR3 SODIMM RAM modules in my laptop, and I want to replace the 2GB for a 4GB that is compatible. So far I haven't been able to find an exact match but I found a very similar with a PC3L label instead of PC3. Can they work together?

My DDR3 SODIMM RAM:

[image]

Memory module in question:

[image]

**Installed RAM**: 4GB DDR3 2Rx8 PC3 12800S 11 10 F2

**Matching RAM**:  4GB DDR3 2Rx8 PC3L 12800S 11 10 F3

**Laptop:** [Toshiba Satellite L645D-S4036](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M5GVJY)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What you are referring to is related to DDR3 memory standardization.

- **DDR3** or **PC3** is the Standard Voltage memory module that operates at
  **1.50V** (JEDEC compliant)
- **DDR3L** or **PC3L** is the Low Voltage memory module that operates at **1.35V**
  (JEDEC compliant)
- **DDR3U** or **PC3U** is the Ultra Low Voltage memory module that operates at
  **1.25V** (still not JEDEC compliant)

Most, if not all PC3L modules can support 1.50V operation, so there shouldn't be any issues in your case

Edit. I've just checked in the Samsung catalogue, and I can confirm now that your Samsung M471B5273CH0 PC3L is dual voltage module. Enjoy :)

[image]

Comment: Is the converse true? My laptop has 4GB "PC3L" - 12800S RAM. Can I install 4GB "PC3" 12800S RAM to upgrade to 8GB ?

Comment: Yes without any issue if your laptop mobbo supports the 1.5V on memory

Comment: There's this excellent article on memory compatibility at Dell
http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN153768/en

Comment: @Navigator Did your PC3 ram work fine together with PC3L ram? I am using a hp laptop and it came with 1Rx8 PC3L ram installed; I just ordered a 1Rx8 PC3 ram and hope they will be compatible with each other.

Comment: @stt106 Did yours work? I'm finding myself at the same situation :)

Comment: @DavidRefoua no, it didn't work. In the end I think it's impossible to tell by yourself whether a ram is going to work on your laptop/pc. I had to use a website that sells  ram and only buy the ones it says it will definitely work on my pc.

Comment: @stt106 Thanks for the update! I think that this is the type of information that should be covered somewhere in the manufacturer's documentation. Sadly those barely contain any information that could be practically useful. I guess it more or less comes down to trial and error.

Comment: Have several laptops of identical model, re-purposed them all.  One gave an error on boot saying it had unsupported DDR3.  Checked the RAM sticks/cards and discovered that the one that doesn't work is the only one that is PC3 rather than PC3L.

Comment: "Most, if not all PC3L modules can support 1.50V operation, so there shouldn't be any issues in your case" - You're implying that using them together will result in the DDR3L module not running at 1.35V?