# What is the difference between 4 GB 1Rx8 PC3L and 4gb 2Rx8 PC3L RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a 4gb 1Rx8 PC3L and a 4 GB 2Rx8 PC3L RAM. I have been searching for answers but what I only see in most forums is comparing 1Rx8 PC3L from 2Rx8 PC3. What is the difference of 1Rx8 and 2Rx8 which are both low voltage RAM (1.35 V)?

Comment: The R stands for Ranking,

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [DIMMS: Single vs double vs quad rank](https://serverfault.com/questions/69612/dimms-single-vs-double-vs-quad-rank)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have PC3L and PC3 RAM together?](https://superuser.com/questions/662033/can-you-have-pc3l-and-pc3-ram-together)